# jQuery, Ajax, JSON, PHP and parsererror

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to send a form to a PHP using `$.ajax` in [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). I send the whole thing as JSON, but, when I try to get the response, I get the 'parsererror'. What am I doing wrong?

jQuery fragment:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: "inscrever_curso.php",
        data: {cpf : $("input#cpf").val(),nome : $("input#nome").val()},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("sucesso: "+data.msg);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert ("erro: "+textStatus);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $return[msg]="Testing, testing.";
    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply - I just added the quotes around msg in PHP and still get the error. :(

Comment: Oh :-( Are you sure it is "parse error" you get from the server ? Is your PHP script no longer than those two lines ? Because those look fine (no parse error, at least) ; you are using PHP >= 5.2, right ?

Comment: Shouldn't the answers starting with "Shouldn't" be comments against the original question and not use up answer space?

Comment: What do you get when you go to `inscrever_curso.php` in your web browser?

Comment: yeah, I was using a larger script before, but since it wasn't working, I tried to make it simple first. IT doesn't work even with this simple script.

Comment: Rob -> Here's what the browser gets me:
{"msg":"Testing, testing."}

Comment: And the 2 lines you gave us here are **exactly** what gives you a parse error on your server ? (A way to get a parse error would be to have forgotten a '$' sign in one of the two '$return', for instance)

Comment: yeah, I just did a copy/paste from my file.

Comment: Ergh ; if there is nothing else in your PHP script than those two lines, I really don't see why you'd get a parse error :-( (I've tested both JS and PHP code, and they seem OK to me / my server / My browser) ; and if the script works OK when you're calling it, it's a bit strange... Ho, maybe an idea : your ajax request is made to inscrever_curso.php ; is that the script you called from your browser ? (maybe you have two scripts with the same name, and you're not testing the right one ? ) -- kinda running out of ideas, actually...

Comment: Refresh with CTRL + F5, maybe your browser cached the page and it isn't retrieving your updated one after adding the quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but here is one thing about your PHP code:

```
$return[msg]="Testing, testing.";
echo json_encode($return);
```

Doing this, with E_NOTICE error_reporting level, you get:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant msg - assumed 'msg'
```

If notices are enabled and displayed on your server, is will cause an output that is not valid JSON (the ouput contains the error message before the JSON string).

To avoid that notice, you must use this syntax:

```
$return['msg']="Testing, testing.";
echo json_encode($return);
```

Note the quotes around `msg`: the key of the array-element you are creating is a string constant, so, it is enclosed in quotes.

If you don't put in these quotes, PHP searches for a [defined](http://php.net/define) constant called "msg", which probably doesn't exist.

For more information about this, you can take a look at this section of the manual: *[Why is $foo[bar] wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)*.

(I am not sure it'll solve your problem, but it's good to know anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

Your PHP code should probably be:

```
<?php
    $return = array();
    $return['msg']="Testing, testing.";
    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found out what was happening: I've got an `.htaccess` script for friendly URLs, and it was searching for the right PHP file, but in the wrong directory. I just added a '/' before the filename in the URL and then it worked.

Comment: Ergh :-D Nice job : we probably wouldn't have found this one ^^ Thanks for letting us know what caused the problem !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone but I just had the json_decode() call but without echo before it. Perfectly valid PHP but will mess up your AJAX response and cause the parsererror.

Comment: Well, if you don't `echo` anything then your response body will be empty and that is not valid JSON and will trigger the parse error in JS if you had set `dataType` to "json" or if your reply header has "Content-Type: application/json" set (as I found out today).